# bluetooth - UUID from peripheral device is a normal String

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Hey I have the problem that a friend of mine build a device that should be connected with the iphone. But now I am building the app and have the problem that I would like to compare the uuid from the peripheral with the my chosen uuid.
If I call the function didDiscoverServices I get stuff like:
Service found with UUID: Device Information
Service found with UUID: Battery

But I cannot compare it with:
if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"Battery"]]) {....}
cause the string isn't a uuid.
What could I do now? Is there any other possibility compare the service?
(service.description is also a random number)

Comment: [service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0x180F"]]

Comment: thanks, then it would be with the Battery example: ...UUIDWithString:@"0x180FBattery"]]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID of Battery is 0x180F according to the doc: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx 
So you have to write: `[service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0x180F"]]` or the UUID your friend put.

You have to understand that UUID in Bluetooth Low Energy are 16-bits OR 128 bits (for custom). Reading the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html or at least the one of `UUIDWithString` should help you to understand.